# Error: SQL statement is nested too deeply. When compiling stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, parse-error

When I try to compile a very large stored procedure in SQL Server 2016, I get the following error:

> Msg 191, Level 15, State 1, Procedure dm_m_proc, Line 9301 [Batch Start Line 8]
>   Some part of your SQL statement is nested too deeply. Rewrite the query or break it up into smaller queries.

So this error appears in SQL Server itself (when compiling the stored procedure), I don't think it is in my SQL code.

The problem occurs when I add one small section to the procedure. For instance, adding the following causes the error:

```
else if @user_id=0
    begin
        print 42 
    end
```

this increases the number of else if to 225, however they are not nested, they are all separate 'else if' statements so no nesting occurs.

I don't believe there is maximum on either stored procedure size or number of else if statements.

Although.. when I add the if statement inside an existing block the procedure compiles fine.

Any help or hints much appreciated.

Comment: There may be a way to simplify what you are doing. If you can post your entire procedure, someone might be able to help with simplification.

Comment: @zedfoxus . . . I doubt that anyone can help if the procedure already has 224 `if` statements.

Comment: `else if` is nested by definition. It opens a new `if` nested in the `else` of the previous one. From the fragment you posted you just need to define a mapping table of userid and values to print

Comment: Seems like you think SQL and languages like C# are the same. SQL isn't a programming language, it's a query language. What ever it is you're trying to do, if you have 224 `IF` statements it seems you think you're using a programming language. You should be using a set based solution.

Comment: @GordonLinoff we could perhaps have OP store userid and value in the database so that it prints value by looking up the key in a database table. That'd get rid of almost all nesting. Just a thought.

Comment: @Larnu . . . Actually in the OP's defense, the OP is writing a stored procedure using T-SQL, which is a scripting language and has little to do with SQL.

Comment: @GordonLinoff "T-SQL has little to do with SQL"...? Not sure what you're saying there, T-SQL is a dialect of SQL; it is certainly related to SQL.

Comment: @Larnu . . . T-SQL is the scripting language.  It doesn't have much to do with SQL -- or at least what is commonly thought of as SQL, the DML and DDL components.

Answer (score 1):

thanks for your help, especially to Martin Smith. I had not considered that using 'else if' would be nested. I managed to replicate the error using a simpler test script. I got to 187 'else if' statements with the 188's statement causing the SQL error.

Now I know the cause I can do a workaround (just have to split up that procedure). Dynamic SQL would solve it quite easily but I am trying to avoid dynamic SQL unless absolutely necessary.